# Python sys.argv and argparser conflict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to mixed-use both argument handlers but failed. Python doesn't allow me to do so or do there exist some ways to handle mixed usage?

```py
import argparse
import sys
# Define an argparse parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', help='foo help')

# Parse the arguments using argparse
args = parser.parse_args()

# Access the value of --foo from argparse
if args.foo:
    print(f'--foo is set to {args.foo}')

# Access the value of sys.argv
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print(f'The first positional argument is {sys.argv[1]}')
```

my running result:

```
# this one ok!
python foo.py "asdasd"    
usage: foo.py [-h] [--foo FOO]
foo.py: error: unrecognized arguments: asdasd

# this one fail!
python foo.py --foo  "asdasd" 
--foo is set to asdasd
The first positional argument is --foo
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `argparse` to handle all arguments?  Why over complicate it?

Comment: I suggest to print the whole `sys.argv`. Is this is what you expect?

Comment: what did you expect to get from `python foo.py --foo "asdasd"`?

Comment: I'm using `argparse ` but some time i want save `-p` flag...

Comment: @Aemyl, This is just reproducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both of them. argparse is a module to handle CLA in a user friendly way. sys.argv is a list that contains your CLA.

```
# Parse the arguments using argparse
args, remaining_args = parser.parse_known_args()

# Access the value of sys.argv
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] not in remaining_args:
   print(f'The first positional argument is {sys.argv[1]}')
```